# Integrating SecuGen HU20 SDK Windows Forms App with ASP.NET Core Web App for Fingerprint Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, rpc

Currently I'm working on a .Net WinForms App of a fingerprint that captures and verifies the fingerprint of the user. The fingerprint device provides SDK for WinForms App development but not for Web App development. The client wants a web based application using ASP NET Core but there is only the SDK for WinForms App. As per their suggestion, they said to create a web-based application using ASP.NET Core that communicates with the existing WinForms Application to perform fingerprint authentication, also said use the concept of RPC. I have no idea what this means and what I shall do. I tried researching about RPC but there were multiple topics on grpc with .net.

Haven't tried anything, I'm stuck.